# How to transfer webform submission ID to client side

Tags: 7, hooks, webforms

I need to transfer the submission ID to the client side after a webform is submitted. The problem is that after submission the Confirmation page is showed. And how can I attach the current sid to a page? I know how to do it on a node (se below) with Drupal behaviors on a client side JS-script.

Anyone? Or maybe the sid can be transfered to the client side another way?

```
function mymodule_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission) {
 // $node will give you the node id of your webform
 // $submission will give you the id of your data which you inserted in web form
 $sid = $submission->sid ? $submission->sid : FALSE;
 if($sid){
   $currentSid = array('mymodule' => array('sid' => $sid));
   $node->content['#attached']['js'][] = array(
     'data' => $currentSid,
     'type' => 'setting',
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by putting the submission id into $_SESSION and add it to Drupal's js settings

```
drupal_add_js(array('mymodule' => array('webform_id' => $_SESSION['webform_id'])), 'setting');
```

Then access it on the client side

```
webform_id = Drupal.settings.mymodule.webform_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please bare with me, I can't get it to work. Where do I add the actual value of the submission ID in the key webform_id?

Comment: Disregard the comment above. I am an idiot... Thanks again for the solution!